# How to reset lstset settings for listings?

Tags: latex

At the top of my tex document, I set my sourcecode listing format by

```
\lstset{language=java}  
\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersep=5pt, breaklines=true}  
\lstset{emph={square}, emphstyle=\color{red}, emph={[2]root,base}, emphstyle {[2]\color{blue}}}
```

because I merely list Java source code. 
At one point in my document, I had to reformat for a single listing by

```
\lstset{commentstyle=\footnotesize\textit}  
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}  
\lstset{literate={!=} {$\neq$}{2}}
```

Now I have the problem that my previous Java formatting for listings is destroyed, and I dont know how to reset the lst settings to default.
How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to modify only one listing, you can pass the options as an optional argument:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[commentstyle=\footnotesize\textit]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

will only affect that particular listing.

Comment: How can I disable numbers localy?